# How to maintain data on an android device even if the app is uninstalled?

Tags: android

I want to maintain data on an android device even if my app is uninstalled.
I want to maintain the data (some key) in android device even when the app is uninstalled or removed i want to retain this data when my app is re-installed in the same device.

Answer (score 2):

A [similar question](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/121413aa0bd1e263#) passed by on Google Groups quite a while ago and as far as I understood, there's not a single method that will fully prevent a user from deleting the data stored. If you think about it, it actually wouldn't make sense to provide a way to fill up a device's (internal) storage without the user being able to free up that space again.

That being said, your options for storing semi-persistant data that does not get wiped out when an app is being uninstalled seem to be limited to either the SD card, some web-based location or a seperate content provider - each with its own limitations.

You might also want to read through [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can save it to a folder and if app is reinstalled, load it from there.

Comment: i want to store it only in device memory not in SD card. If we are saving the data(files or folders) in the internal storage then it will be wiped out when the app is uninstalled.